# Condition not behaving properly at iPad

Tags: ios

In my app, I have if-else condition the issue is this condition behaving  properly on simulator (iPhone as well iPad) and iPhone Device too But not Behaving properly on ipad device. Is it possible to solve this issue?

```
if (_loginForCoDriver ) {
    NSString *name=[[APPDELEGATE.coDeriverDetailArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];

    NSString *password=[[APPDELEGATE.coDeriverDetailArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"driver_pass"];
    //[[APPDELEGATE.coDeriverDetailArr objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"driver_pass"];

    if ((usernametext.text==name) && (passwordtext.text==password) ) {
         [self logoutAPI];
        //modeStr=@"Logging";
        [ProgressHUD show:@"Please wait..." Interaction:NO];
        //https://mobile.epgsolutions.net/

        //   NSString *strURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://projects.udaantechnologies.com/epg_services/user_login.php"];
        NSString *strURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_baseurl,@"user_login.php"];
        // NSString *strURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://mobile.epgsolutions.net/user_login.php"];

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
        [request setDelegate:self];

        [request setPostValue:usernametex.text forKey:@"number"];
        [request setPostValue:passwordtex.text forKey:@"password"];
        [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"device_type"];
        [request setPostValue:APPDELEGATE.deviceTokenStr forKey:@"access_token"];
        [request setUploadProgressDelegate:self];
        [request setTimeOutSeconds:200000.0];
        [request startAsynchronous];
    }
    else{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Id/Password doesn't Match !" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Re-Enter" otherButtonTitles:@"Go Back", nil] show];

                }

   }
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead.
From iOS8 Apple provide new UIAlertController class which you can use instead of UIAlertView which is now deprecated, its is also stated in depreciation message.

i read your code, its perfect and found nothing except this UIAlertView.

May be this will work.

Comment: in iPhone its working properly and simulator too. having issue with iPad only.in iPad it's jumping to else condition while if condition is true.

Comment: I agree. It's time to upgrade to ui alert controller.

Comment: Make sure your iPad runs on latest iOS version.